# cant update in mongoDb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a followers/following function in my project. However I cannot seem to update the DB correctly. I'm able to send the ids as they both print when I console.log but nothing in my DB updates and I do not get any response in my frontend.

route

```
app.put('/api/follow', async function (req, res, next){
    const { id } = req.query;
    const userFrom = req.body.data

    console.log('OTHER USER ID',id)
    console.log('CURRENT ID', userFrom)

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(id), {
      $push:{followers:req.body.data}
    },{new:true},
  (err,result)=>{
    if(err) {
      if(err) return res.status(400).send(err)
    }
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.data), {
      $push:{following:id}
    },{new:true}.then(result=> {
      res.json(result)
    }).catch(err=>{
      return res.status(422).json({error:err})
    })   
  }
  })
```

user model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const User = mongoose.model(

      "User",
      new mongoose.Schema({
        username: String,
        email: String,
        password: String,
        phoneNo: String,
        bio: String,
        filePath: String,
        following: [
          {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
          },
        ],
        followers: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "User",
        },
      })
    );
    
    module.exports = User;
```

my route end function

```
const clickHandler = () => {
        
        const currentID = currentUser.id;
        const id = this.props.id;
        
        console.log('CURRENT ID',currentID)
        console.log('otherUserID',id)
    
        Axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/api/follow/?id=${id}`,  { data: currentID }, { headers: authHeader() })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.success) {
                console.log('FOLLOWED', response.data)
                // this.setState({ userDetails: response.data.details })
            } else {
                alert('Error')
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be
`User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {`

You should not close the bracket after id but after `new: true})`

Comment: thanks, however now the data is not successful when returning